# How to render form field inside list item in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a List with elements. How can I render formfield inside list item, so that when user clicks on list item, this field gets focus, and user can enter a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose in the itemTpl config on your list you can add html input / text fields

```
        xtype:'list',
        disableSelection:true,
        store: 'Store',
        itemTpl:'<TR><TH>INFO</TH><TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="name" SIZE="20"></TD></TR>' ,
```